# Unique existential quantifier in Boolean-valued models

Tags: logic, set-theory

I had the following basic question on Boolean-valued models. In Boolean-valued models and Independence proofs (John Bell, 2011), Bell in Open Problem 1.29 infers from $\exists ! x \varphi(x) $ that there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $1=[[ \exists x \varphi(x)]]= \bigvee_{x \in \mathbf{V}_{\alpha}} [[ \varphi(x)]]$. But how to justify this step?

Is there some short proof for:

If  $[[\exists x \varphi(x) \wedge \forall y ( \varphi(y) \rightarrow x=y)]]=1$, then there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\bigvee_{x \in \mathbf{V}_{\alpha}} [[ \varphi(x)]] = 1$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of such an ordinal has little to do with whether $V^B \models \exists ! x \varphi(x)$... that's not where it's being inferred from.

Instead, note that $A := \{\Vert \varphi(u) \Vert : u\in V^B\}$ is a set, since $B$ is a set. For each $a\in A,$ let $\gamma_a$ be the least ordinal $\gamma$ such that there is a $u\in V^B_\gamma$ with $\Vert \varphi(u) \Vert = a.$ Then take $\alpha = \sup_{a\in A} \gamma_a,$ and we have $$ \Vert \exists x \varphi(x)\Vert = \bigvee_{u\in V^B}\Vert \varphi(u)\Vert = \bigvee_{u\in V^B_\alpha}\Vert \varphi(u) \Vert.$$

So the only place the assumption that $V^B\models\exists! x\varphi(x)$ is used in this part is just to say that $\Vert \exists x \varphi(x)\Vert = 1.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !!!